# How to clear the form on buttonClick

Tags: reactjs

I have created a form using Material UI in React Functional Component which needs to be cleared on button click event. Below is the code of the form

```
  <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <Grid container item xs={12} alignItems="center">
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>1</Avatar>
        <label className={classes.LableStyle}>
          Name
      </label>
      </Grid>

      <Grid container item xs={12} alignItems="center">
        <TextField
          id="outlined-bare"
          className={classes.textField1}
          defaultValue=""
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{ style: { height: 40 } }}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'Name')}
        />
      </Grid>
  </Form>
```

As its evident that i am capturing user inputs using event `onChange` which is available in my ConatinerComponent. Similarly, how can i create an event in my ContainerComponent which can clear my form?

Comment: You are not capturing the user inputs, just the first letter of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing any value to your input, so it is not a React controlled input (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). You can still manipulate its value through the DOM, but you will need to remove the onChange handler and add a name to your form to access its rendered node.

Otherwise, you can just pass a value as a prop to TextField, making it a controlled component.

Here is an example:

```js
const TextField = props => (<input type="text" value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange}/>)

class Form extends React.Component {
    state = {
        Name: ''
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do something with your data
        // then reset
        this.setState({
            Name: ''
        })
    }

    handleChange = (e, prop) => {
        this.setState({[prop]: e.target.value})
    }
    
    render() {
        return (<form ref={this.form} noValidate="noValidate" autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <TextField id="outlined-bare" defaultValue="" margin="normal" variant="outlined" InputProps={{
                    style: {
                        height: 40
                    }
                }} value={this.state.Name} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'Name')}/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```